# looping through arrays of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an arrays of arrays (some thing like graph), How to iterate all arrays?

```
var parentArray = [
 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
 [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]],
 [[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[26,27,28]]
];
```

Its just an example array, actual can contains any number of array and then arrays. How to print all those numbers? Its similar to html objects DOM

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419537/enhanced-for-loop-in-2d-array-javascript

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This recursive function should do the trick with any number of dimensions:

```
var printArray = function(arr) {
    if ( typeof(arr) == "object") {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            printArray(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    else document.write(arr);
}

printArray(parentArray);
```

Comment: well, the name is too obvious :)

Comment: Just for heads up ```typeof(arr) == "object"``` could be ```arr instanceof Array``` and it wouldn't try to loop over {Objects:''} :-)

Answer (score 18):

For 2 dimenional Arrays:

```
for(var i = 0; i < parentArray.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < parentArray[i].length; j++){

        console.log(parentArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

For arrays with an unknown number of dimensions you have to use recursion:

```
function printArray(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] instanceof Array){
            printArray(arr[i]);
        }else{
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

what you need to do is something like this

```
var parentArray = [
 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
 [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]],
 [[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[26,27,28]]
];

for(int i = 0; i < parentArray.length;i++){
   var value = parent[i];

   for(int j = 0; j < parent[i].length; j++){
      var innerValue = parent[i][j];
   }
}
```

So this will be like a nested loop, then there where innerValue and value is you can do some operations, hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use recursion which works with **any number of dephts**. See `traverse()`, it's not tested but should give a rough idea:

```
String.prototype.lpad = function(padString, length) {
    var str = this;
    while (str.length < length)
        str = padString + str;
    return str;
}

var level = 0;

function traverse(obj) {
   if (obj instanceof Array) { level++; for(var i in obj) traverse(obj[i]); level--; }
   else console.log(''.lpad('-', level) + obj);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you just want to print all the members,how about this?

```
var items = parentArray.toString().split(",");
for(var i=0,j=items.length;i<j;i++)
    console.log(items[i]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [array.forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) method

```
parentArray.forEach( function(childArray) {
  childArray.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item);
  });
 });

[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 10, 11, 12 ]
[ 13, 14, 15 ]
[ 16, 17, 18 ]
[ 19, 20, 21 ]
[ 22, 23, 24 ]
[ 26, 27, 28 ]
```

One liner using => "fat arrow"  in ES6+

```
parentArray.forEach(subarray => { subarray.forEach( item => {console.log(item); }); });


[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 10, 11, 12 ]
[ 13, 14, 15 ]
[ 16, 17, 18 ]
[ 19, 20, 21 ]
[ 22, 23, 24 ]
[ 26, 27, 28 ]
```

If you want to list individual number in item, add another layer of forEach.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a DOM like structure, you need to recursively iterate through the elements. Something like that should work:

```
function printArray(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var v = array[i];
        if (v instanceof Array) {
            printArray(v);
        } else {
            console.log(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is new or what, but it may please you to know that there is an Array prototype ".flat" that can be used here to make the array one-dimensional:

```
var parentArray = [
 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
 [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]],
 [[19,20,21],[22,23,24],[26,27,28]]
];

function flatten(){
flatArray = parentArray.flat(Infinity);
flatArray.forEach(function(item, i){
  console.log(item)
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use nested for loops here. The outer loop would iterate the parent array, giving you one of the internal arrays each time. The inner loop would give you the items within each array.
Example:

```
for(childArray in parentArray){
    for(item in childArray){
        //do stuff here to each number
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not loop over arrays with `for in`.

Comment: I agree, it's not the best choice. I suggest reading before trying to use it http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html

Answer (score 0):

How to loop an indefinite nested array in JavaScript:

```js
function isArray(x) {
  return typeof x === "object";
}

let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [5, [2, 3, 4], 3], [[[0]]]];

function loop_map(x, idx) {
  x.map((res, i) => {
    console.log("Index ", i);
    if (isArray(res)) {
      loop_map(res, i);
    } else {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
}

loop_map(x, 0);
```

Comment: this algorithm can be used to search

Answer (score 0):

```
const parentArray = [
  [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
  ],
  [
    [10,11,12],
    [13,14,15],
    [16,17,18]
  ],
  [
    [19,20,21],
    [22,23,24],
    [26,27,28]
  ]
]

parentArray.map(
  childArray => childArray.map(
    grandChildArray => grandChildArray.map(
      arrayItem => console.log(arrayItem)
    )
  )
)
```