# How to loop through an array of arrays using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json array like this

```
var data = key: [
    {
        arr1: [
            {value: 1},
            {value: 2},
            {value: 3},
        ]
    },
    {
        arr2: [
            {value: 1},
            {value: 2},
            {value: 3},
        ]
    },
    {
        arr3: [
            {value: 1},
            {value: 2},
            {value: 3},
        ]
    }
]
```

I wanted to loop through `key` which is 3 times, and inside the key loop I wanted loop again through each of the elements inside `key`.

First I tried `$.each` which works fine for key array. And inside the each function I tried to get the key values using `Object.key(this)` inside the loop which returned me the names

```
arr1, arr2, arr3
```

But I'm not able to loop through the names I got.

```
$.each(data, function(i, e) {
    Object.keys(this).each(function(index, element) {
        console.log(element);
    })    
})
```

I don't know if this is the right way of doing it, when I tried doing it this was. I got an error telling `.each` is not a function.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: because an array does not have an each method.... Arrays have forEach...

Comment: Something like this works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106410/looping-through-arrays-of-arrays

Comment: If you realy like jQuery, try use `$(Object.keys(this)).each( ... )`.

Comment: What is that stray `key:` there in the first line? The code defining your object is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple way to do this would be to use three loops, but trying to make that work with `this` taking on a new meaning in each loop would be unnecessarily complicated.

I recommend using `.forEach` and giving a clear name to each loop variable:

```js
var data =  [
    {
        arr1: [
            {value: 1},
            {value: 2},
            {value: 3},
        ]
    },
    {
        arr2: [
            {value: 1},
            {value: 2},
            {value: 3},
        ]
    },
    {
        arr3: [
            {value: 1},
            {value: 2},
            {value: 3},
        ]
    }
]

data.forEach(function (outerObj) {
  Object.keys(outerObj).forEach(function (key) {
    outerObj[key].forEach(function (item) {
      console.log(item);
    });
  });
});
```

Of course, there may be a better solution if you would actually tell us what you wanted to accomplish with these loops.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep with the jQuery pattern, then just keep using `each` for each nested level:

```js
var data = [{arr1: [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}]}, {arr2: [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}]}, {arr3: [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}]}];

$.each(data, function(i, e) {
    $.each(e, function(key, arr) {
        console.log(key);
        $.each(arr, function(index, obj) {
            console.log("...", index, obj.value);
        });
    });
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I tried passing the `e` to `$.each` it wasn't working. So I switched to `this.each` which didn't work as well. But in your answer it works. +1

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason your attempt is not working is because you are trying to `.each` the individual values themselves, rather than the arrays within `data`.

This should work:

```
$.each(data, function(index, array) { // This each iterates over the arrays.
  $.each(array, function(subindex, value) { // This each iterates over the individual values.
    console.log(value); // Logs the individual values.
  });
});
```