# How to Iterate Array of Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, arraylist

I have an array of array data. I want to loop array of array value and get the first values of each array.

```
var myArr= [
 ["1",10],
 ["2",20],
 ["3",34]
]
```

I need to get the first value of each array. Here first value is a string value. How to get "1","2","3" these string value using loop.

Comment: This is a **very** basic question, that you should be able to search for.  What research have you done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106410/looping-through-arrays-of-arrays

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArr= [
 ["1",10],
 ["2",20],
 ["3",34]
]

console.log(myArr.map(item=>item[0]));
```

You could use `map` function. This will return an array containing only the first values of each array in the main array.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: He doesn't need a map.  He just needs to loop over the first, and only, element in the outer most array.  A simple search engine attempt at "loop over an array in javascript" would tell him how to do this.

Comment: Agreed! Just wanted to show the capabilities of array functions in Javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

to iterate over an array and just do an action with it you can use .forEach
if you would like to iterate over an array and return a new array you can use .map

in this case to just log the first item of each sub array you can

```
myArr.forEach(x => console.log(x[0])
```