# How iterate an ArrayList inside various others ArrayLists?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I was notified that is possible to create "infinite" ArrayLists inside others, such as in the code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>>>> List = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>>>>();
    }
}
```

And I want know about how to iterate them (with foreach or other loop types)

Comment: Java's type system doesn't like it when you do stuff like this. In any case, the only practical way to iterate through arbitrarily-deeply-nested lists is with recursion

Comment: If you have a data structure like this, you are doing a lot of things wrong. Time to rethink some dicisions. Apart from that a list of lists is just a list. So you can iterate it like any other list.

Comment: Really it's doing the things much more difficult that should be

Comment: Madness this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to traverse it like a composite:

```java
public static void traverse(ArrayList<T> arg) {
   arg.forEach(
    (n) -> if (n instanceof ArrayList) { 
        traverse(n)
      } else {
        doStomething(n)
      }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to understand it and use for decode the loop.

Comment: I've searching how do this is other languages, and you answer is very similar of this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106410/looping-through-arrays-of-arrays

Comment: yep, it's the same concept

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, if someone writes such structures - it's some kind of a maniac.
But still, you can follow this kind of pattern in order to traverse:

````
@Test
    public void test4() {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("abc");
        list1.add("def");

        List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(list1);

        list2.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```
````

Comment: Interesting answer, seems more simple than the Vulwsztyn solution,
although his answer like more robust, I not understand well.

Comment: What this component does :: ?

Comment: @UserOfStackOverFlow this is a short way to reference an existing method within lambda.

E.g.:
'flatMap(Collection::stream)' can be replaced with 'flatMap(param -> param.stream())', which would make it look longer without any neccessity.

You can find more detailed info here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-references